# Installation freezes at 33% of partition formatting step

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning, hp, hyper-v

**Goal**

I am attempting to install ubuntu server OS within a Virtual machine on a HP gen 8 microserver. I am running the Hyper-V Hypervisor under Windows Server 2016.

**Issue:**

During the partition formatting stage of the installation, the process freezes/fails at 33%.

[image]

```
Filename: ubuntu-14.04.3-server-i386.iso
MD5: 352009d5b44f0e97c9558919f0147c0c
```

**Steps performed pre install:**

1. Installed Windows Server 2016 on microserver (8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, 2TB HDD Array with RAID10).
2. Installed Hyper-v role under server manager.
3. Created VM with appropriate virtual hardware resources.
4. Created a virtual switch so VM has external
   internet access and assign it to VM.

**What I've tried to fix the issue:**

- Storing the virtual hard disk on a different drive (I've tried the SSD & HDD)
- Changing the size of the Virtual drive and assigning more RAM.
- Installing different versions of the Ubuntu OS ISO. I tried the desktop version and the same thing happens but the timezone/map screen freezes instead.
- Leaving the installation overnight just in case it's working but my system is just acting slow.
- Updating RAID drivers from HP http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5387585&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4231
- Playing around with the manual settings pre drive format step.

**Question:**

I've kind of hit a brick wall and at the point of giving up trying to install Ubuntu. Is this a known bug? As you can see, I've got a pretty standard setup but something isn't quite right. How can I better debug the installation step so I can see exactly what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug.  If the partition already has a filesystem on it, this step will hang in 14.04 iirc, but it has been fixed in 16.04, so you probably should use that instead.  As a workaround, run `wipefs` on the partition to clear it, then the install should work.